# videobrush orientation does not match phone orientation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to match the videobrush orientation to the orientation of the phone, but I am having issues implementing this solution. My xaml page is set to PortraitOrLandscape, and I would like for the videobrush to be right side up regardless of the phone's orientation. Before adding the orientation changing if statements to the onOrentationChanged event, the following situation is occuring

Phone: Landscape left, Videobrush: right side up

Phone: Portrait, Videobrush, rotated -90 clockwise

Phone: Landscape right, Videobrush, rotated -180 clockwise

XAML

```
<Rectangle x:Name="videoRectangle" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                    <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderTransform" 
                                            CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </VideoBrush>                    
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
```

XAML.CS

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnOrientationChanged(e);

        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
        {                //do nothing
                         //The videobrush orientation is currently right side up
        }
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.Portrait)
        {
            //the videobrush is currently rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise
            this.viewfinderTransform.Rotation = this.camera.Orientation + 90.0;
        }
        if (e.Orientation == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            //the videobrush is currently rotated 180 degrees counter clockwise
            this.viewfinderTransform.Rotation = this.camera.Orientation + 180;
        }
    }
```

And after adding the if statements, the videobrush orientation gets even crazier. What am I doing wrong? I simply would like to have the videobrush oriented right side up regardless of the phone's orientation.

Comment: There's something else going on besides what you are showing. The XAML (without the codebehind) works as you'd expect in the emulator and on my phone. Albeit, I'm not sure why you are using a `VisualBrush` to paint a `Rectangle`, or providing a transform that centers a `UniformToFill` object.

Comment: this.viewfinderTransform.Rotation = this.camera.Orientation;
this doesnt work?

Comment: @Ritch I am just referencing a few MSDN sources I have found regarding painting an object (rectangle) with a videobrush. In my case, UniformToFill works best because I do not want any differences in width and height when rotating my phone between portrait and landscape (I have noticed the videobrush image is stretched and squeezed while doing this), and UniformToFill gives the same persepective throughout the rotation of the device.

Comment: @NOOB `this.viewfinderTransform.Rotation = this.camera.Orientation;` does rotate the videobrush but not according to how I have commented in my code behind (which I thought would be the most logical solution). Any ideas?

Comment: @Matthew - Is there something else involved. Your xaml works just fine for me.

Comment: @Ritch i do have a couple more methods for an orientation lock feature but the code inside them is only activited on a click event. I believe once the 'lock current orientation' button has been clicked is when everything starts to mess up. I am going to go back and start fresh to check out the functionality, since it has worked correctly for you. If this is the case, how would you go about setting a lock orientation feature correctly?

Comment: @Matthew - I don't know what I would do. Well, I probably wouldn't do it, as someone who wants to lock the orientation can just hold the phone in that orientation already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using a simple switch/case to properly rotate the videobrush:

```
protected override void OnOrientationChanged(OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnOrientationChanged(e);
  switch (e.Orientation)
  {
    case PageOrientation.Landscape:
    case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
      videoBrushTransform.Rotation = 0;
      break;
    case PageOrientation.LandscapeRight:
      videoBrushTransform.Rotation = 180;
      break;
    case PageOrientation.Portrait:
    case PageOrientation.PortraitUp:
      videoBrushTransform.Rotation = 90;
      break;
    case PageOrientation.PortraitDown:
      videoBrushTransform.Rotation = 270;
      break;
  }
}
```

Works nicely for me.

Comment: exactly what i have used :-)